# HTML document no icon?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, html, file-association

All my HTML documents on my PC do not show an icon as shown on the image below:

[image]

Firefox is set as my default browser. How can I configure an icon for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set File Associations in Windows 7, Open Control Panel > Control Panel Home > Default Programs > Set Associations. Select a file type in the list and click Change Program.

Alternatively, you can also Right click the file whose association you want to change > Properties > General tab > Type Of File > Change > Choose a program from the list or recommended or other programs or else click Browse to select one.

Reference: [How To Set or Change File Associations in Windows 7 & Vista !](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t19.html)

Comment: This works for other programs besides Firefox, but not for Firefox.  If you switch to Firefox, the icon is blank, as above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other answer but it just left the white icon when I selected Firefox.  What worked is uninstalling Firefox and reinstalling it from the exe from getfirefox.com.  Now the HTML file icons were restored to have the Firefox logo.